# unable to deploy any function to firebase because typescript error

Tags: typescript, firebase, cloud

I'm trying to deploy to Firebase functions however when I use the command "Firebase deploy" is always appearing the same error:

```
Found 230 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-25T10_53_37_578Z-debug.log
```

I see similar problems around Stack Overflow however no one works for me, any idea? Here is my package.json file where I established my packages for node_modules:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "camelcase-keys": "^6.2.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^7.0.4",
    "googleapis": "^71.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-apple-receipt-verify": "^1.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node-apple-receipt-verify": "^1.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```